# On linear dependence of four vectors in a space of dimention 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimention 2 and $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ are any four vectors in $V.$ Then we always can find constants $\{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\}$ not all zero such that 
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4=0$$

But Can we choose $c_i$'s such that along with the above equation, $c_i$'s also satisfiy
$$c_1c_4=c_2c_3$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$.

> **Summary of the answer**: It depends on the field on which $V$ is defined.  If it's algebraically closed (like $\Bbb C$), then the answer is *yes*, otherwise, we need to see whether the determinant of a quadratic eqaution is positive.

### Case 1: $\dim \mathop{\rm span}(S) = 1$

Then $v_1=v_2=v_3=v_4=v$.  Choose $c_1 = c_4 = 1, c_2 = c_3 = -1$.

### Case 2: $\dim \mathop{\rm span}(S) = 2 = \dim(V)$

WLOG, assume $V = \mathop{\rm span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. $\exists \alpha_{31},\alpha_{32},\alpha_{41},\alpha_{42}\in \Bbb R$ such that

\begin{cases}
v_3=\alpha_{31}v_1+\alpha_{32}v_2\\
v_4=\alpha_{41}v_1+\alpha_{42}v_2.
\end{cases}

#### Case 2.1: $v_3,v_4$ linear dependent

$\exists t \in \Bbb R$ such that $v_4 = t v_3$.  Choose $c_1=c_2=0,c_3=t,c_4=-1$.

#### Case 2.2: $v_3,v_4$ linear independent

Using the linear independence of $v_1,v_2$, eliminate $v_3,v_4$.

\begin{cases}
c_1+c_3\alpha_{31}+c_4\alpha_{41}&=0\\
c_2+c_3\alpha_{32}+c_4\alpha_{42}&=0\\
c_1c_4&=c_2c_3
\end{cases}

If $c_1=c_2=0$, the above system becomes

\begin{cases}
c_3\alpha_{31}+c_4\alpha_{41}&=0\\
c_3\alpha_{32}+c_4\alpha_{42}&=0
\end{cases}

By the linear independence of $v_3,v_4$, $c_3=c_4=0$, which is not something we want.

If $c_1\ne0,c_2=0\implies c_4=0$.  From $\sum_{i=1}^4 c_iv_i=0$, one must conclude that $v_1$ and $v_3$ are linearly dependent if the conditions of the question are satified.

Similarly, if $c_1=0,c_2\ne0\implies c_3=0$.  From $\sum_{i=1}^4 c_iv_i=0$, one must conclude that $v_2$ and $v_4$ are linearly dependent if the conditions of the question are satified.

If $c_1,c_2\ne0$, $c_3,c_4\ne0$ (otherwise, using $c_1c_4=c_2c_3$, $c_3 = 0\implies c_4=0$, which implies $c_1=c_2=0$.)  Rewrite the system of equations into

\begin{cases}
\frac{c_1}{c_3}+\alpha_{31}+\frac{c_4}{c_3}\alpha_{41}&=0\\
\frac{c_2}{c_4}+\frac{c_3}{c_4}\alpha_{32}+\alpha_{42}&=0\\
\frac{c_1}{c_3}&=\frac{c_2}{c_4}
\end{cases}

This gives us $$\alpha_{31}+\frac{c_4}{c_3}\alpha_{41}=\frac{c_3}{c_4}\alpha_{32}+\alpha_{42}=-\frac{c_1}{c_3}=-\frac{c_2}{c_4}$$

Let $\lambda = \dfrac{c_3}{c_4}$.  Then we have a quadratic equeation $$\alpha_{32}\lambda^2+(\alpha_{42}-\alpha_{31})\lambda-\alpha_{41}=0.$$

If any of $\alpha{ij} = 0$, from the definition of $\alpha{ij}$, one can, using the way of case 2.1, immediately find non-zero constants $c_i,c_j$ such that $c_iv_i+c_jv_j=0$.  Thus, assume $\alpha_{ij} \ne 0 \forall i,j$.  Next, the determinant

$$\Delta=(\alpha_{42}-\alpha_{31})^2+4\alpha_{32}\alpha_{41}.$$

If $V$ is defined on the field $\Bbb C$ (or other algebraically closed field), then we'll have no problem of writing $$\lambda = \frac{\alpha_{31}-\alpha_{42}\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2\alpha_{32}}.$$

Otherwise, if the field is not algebraically closed (e.g. $\Bbb R$), we need $\Delta \ge 0$.

Now, if we can find $\sqrt\Delta$ in the field on which $V$ is defined, we may freely choose $c_4$, then compute $c_3 = \lambda c_4$.  Use them to get

\begin{cases}
c_1&=-c_3\alpha_{31}-c_4\alpha_{41}\\
c_2&=-c_3\alpha_{32}-c_4\alpha_{42}
\end{cases}

Then $\sum_{i=1}^4 c_iv_i=0$ and $c_1c_4=c_2c_3$.